# $\displaystyle\dfrac{a(x)}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}b(\tau)d\tau \sim \dfrac{2}{1-\alpha}\dfrac{\sqrt{a(x)}}{x^{3/2}}, \ \text{when} \ x \to 0.$

Tags: real-analysis

Knowing that $b,a \in C^{0}((0,L]) \cap C^{1}((0,L))$, are positive and $b(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{xa(x)}}$. Assume that $0 < \alpha < 1$ and
$$
\int_{0}^{x}b(\tau)d\tau  \sim \dfrac{2}{1-\alpha}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{a(x)}}, \ \ \text{when} \ \ x \to 0
$$
Then
$$\dfrac{a(x)}{x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}b(\tau)d\tau \sim \dfrac{2}{1-\alpha}\dfrac{\sqrt{a(x)}}{x^{3/2}},  \ \ \text{when} \ \ x \to 0.$$

I'm trying to understand the above implication which is a passage from the proof of Lemma 5.12 of
[Martinez & Vancostenoble - Carleman estimates for one-dimensional degenerate heat equations](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00028-006-0214-6).

It seems to be simple, I'm trying to apply L'hopital's rule. Basically what the author of the article did was multiply $\dfrac{a(x)}{x^{2}}$ by the limit of $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}b(\tau)d\tau$. Why is this possible?

Comment: If you're going to `\dfrac` your fractions, please also `\displaystyle` your integrals: $\displaystyle\frac{a(x)}{x^2}\int_0^x b(\tau)\mathrm d\tau$ `\displaystyle\frac{a(x)}{x^2}\int_0^x b(\tau)\mathrm d\tau` looks better than $\dfrac{a(x)}{x^2}\int_0^x b(\tau)d\tau$ `\dfrac{a(x)}{x^2}\int_0^x b(\tau)d\tau` (though it's better not to `\displaystyle` titles at all).  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: I don't think there's anything involved here. You just multiplied both sides by $a/x^2$, which is certainly justified if $\sim$ has the standard meaning $A\sim B \iff A/B\to 1$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you!